# MDX WHERE: "AND" between several conditions

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho

This MDX request **works**:

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE [Area].[Shanghai]
```

This one **works** too  (different WHERE condition):

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE EXCEPT([Product].[All Products].Children, {[Product].[All Products].[#null]})
```

**Question:** How do I write a request with **both conditions**?
*i.e. area condition AND product condition*

I tried `,` and `AND` but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to define a set within your slicer:

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE 
     [Area].[Shanghai] 
     * EXCEPT([Product].[All Products].Children
             , {[Product].[All Products].[#null]})
```

Pay attention that MDX slicer is not a SQL WHERE statement; you might have a look to MDX sub-select instead.

Comment: Thanks it works! Detail: missing closing parenthesis at the end of the query, you might want to add it.

Answer (score 2):

USE `*` Instead of `AND` or `,`.
It works
Your welcome

Comment: Would you mind writing the whole query, to make things extra clear? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the results you need: (Sub-select)

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT [Area].[Shanghai] on 0 from [SalesAnalysis])
WHERE EXCEPT([Product].[All Products].Children, {[Product].[All Products].[#null]})
```

Comment: Apparently my MDX engine (Mondrian) does not like this sub-select: Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line 3, column 7, token '('

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
    [Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM 
   [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE  
   {   
       [Product].[All Products].Children, 
       [Product].[All Products].[#null] 
   }
```

Comment: ?? The Shanghai condition does not appear in your request.

Comment: I tried something inspired from your syntax, but it does not work. I can't place my two conditions in the same accolade with a comma, I get: Mondrian Error:All arguments to function '{}' must have same hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE
 StripCalculatedMembers(CROSSJOIN(
   {[Area].[Shangai]},
   EXCEPT([Product].[All Products].Children, {[Product].[All Products].[#null]})))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use * instead of AND.

Example:

```
select {[Measures].Members} ON COLUMNS, 
       {[Product].Members} ON ROWS
       from [data_cube]
       where {[Location].[New York] * [Time].[2015]}
```

In your case it should be something like this:

```
SELECT [Measures].salescount ON COLUMNS,
[Date].[2010] ON ROWS
FROM [SalesAnalysis]
WHERE EXCEPT([Product].[All Products].Children, {[Product].[All Products].[#null]}) * [Area].[Shanghai]
```